# Convertir un numero a una cadena en mysql

Tags: mysql, conversión-de-tipos

deseo convertir un número flotante como `150.5` a una cadena de texto, de forma que me quede `Ciento cincuenta punto cinco` ¿Alguien sabe alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: No existe nada en mysql que te lo haga, tendrás que hacerlo de forma manual

Comment: @JavierCano, manual como un decode por ejemplo?

Comment: Dale un vistazo a lo siguiente, se emplean procedimiento almacenados para ello: http://deletesql.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=379 y https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?71,360986,360986

Comment: Gracias! @Garduño

Comment: Aqui hay un ejemplo en Javascript tal vez puedas llevarlo a trasact-SQL https://gist.github.com/alfchee/e563340276f89b22042a

Comment: Has tenido suerte, imagínate tener que hacer el procedimiento que indica @Garduño desde cero...